# XOR'ing bitstrings

Tags: python, byte, xor

I am trying to implements an RC4 encrypt/decrypt of plaintext and I've been stuck on the XOR step for a while now.

My code looks like this :

```
def byteXOR(a, b):
    #TODO take two lists of byte string and return a list with the xor product of them
    u = a.split()
    v = b.split()
    print('Fst: \t {}'.format(u))
    print('Snd: \t {} \n'.format(v))

    '''Fill inn 0' if a bit is shorter than the other'''
    for x,y in zip(u, v):
        if len(x) != len(y):
            if len(x) < len(y):
                x.zfill(len(y) - len(x))
            elif len(x) > len(y):
                y.zfill(len(x) - len(y))

    xor = [ord(x) ^ ord(y) for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
    print('Fst: \t {}'.format(u))
    print('Snd: \t {}'.format(v))
    print('XOR: \t {}'.format(xor))
    return xor

p = "1111 1010001 10111111 11111010 10101011"
q = "1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111"
byteXOR(p, q)
```

I get this output:

```
Fst:     ['1111', '1010001', '10111111', '11111010', '10101011']
Snd:     ['1101000', '1100101', '1101100', '1101100', '1101111'] 

Fst:     ['1111', '1010001', '10111111', '11111010', '10101011']
Snd:     ['1101000', '1100101', '1101100', '1101100', '1101111']
XOR:     [0, 0, 1, 0, 16, 1, 0, 17, 1, 1, 0, 1, 17, 1, 1, 17, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 16, 1, 17, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 16, 17, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

The first problem I can't seem to solve is how to make sure the bit strings are of the same length, 
I used the builtin method zfill() but when I print the lists they are unchanged.

The second problem I have is how to get the desired output of the XOR product of the n'th elements from each list, like this:

```
Fst:      ['0001111', '1010001', '10111111', '11111010', '10101011']
Snd:      ['1101000', '1100101', '01101100', '01101100', '01101111']
XOR:      ['0110011', '0110100', '11010011', '10010110', '11000100']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding XOR-ing you need convert `str`s to `int`s, use `^`, then convert to `bin` representation, to make it between according element of your list you might use `map` i.e.:

```
Fst = ['0001111', '1010001', '10111111', '11111010', '10101011']
Snd = ['1101000', '1100101', '01101100', '01101100', '01101111']
result = list(map(lambda x,y: bin(int(x,2)^int(y,2)), Fst, Snd))
print(result)
```

Output

```
['0b1100111', '0b110100', '0b11010011', '0b10010110', '0b11000100']
```

Note that `bin` returns representation starting with `0b` and as few digit as possible, so if you want to have fixed width without `0b` you need to jettison two first characters and then use `zfill` i.e.

```
final_result = [i[2:].zfill(8) for i in result]
print(final_result)
```

Output:

```
['01100111', '00110100', '11010011', '10010110', '11000100']
```

Note second optional argument for `int` function allowing specifing base of number, it can be any value from `2` to `36`. For example:

```
print(int('FFF',16))
```

outputs:

```
4095
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
def byteXOR(a, b):
    u = [int(bits, 2) for bits in a.split()]
    v = [int(bits, 2) for bits in b.split()]
    xor =  [f ^ s for (f, s) in zip(u, v)]
    print(" ".join([bin(bits).replace("0b", "") for bits in xor]))
    return xor

p = "1111 1010001 10111111 11111010 10101011"
q = "1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111"
byteXOR(p, q)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem, `str.zfill()` returns a new string, it doesn't modify the original string. As such, you have to reassign it to your variables:

```
for x,y in zip(u, v):
    if len(x) != len(y):
        if len(x) < len(y):
            x = x.zfill(len(y) - len(x))
        elif len(x) > len(y):
            y = y.zfill(len(x) - len(y))
```

For your second problem, you can cast the strings to `int()` and pass a `base=2` parameter to say its in binary. You can then do the XOR '^' on the integers, then cast it back to a binary string using `bin()`

```
x = '0001111'
y = '1101000'

x = int(x, base=2)
y = int(y, base=2)

z = str(bin(x ^ y))[2:]  # remove the trailing 0b from the string
print(z)
```

Output:

```
1100111
```

That being said, since `int(string, base=2)` converts a string to integers, you really don't need to `zfill()` the bytes first, and you can use `zip()` to do this in one line as follows:

```
p = "1111 1010001 10111111 11111010 10101011"
q = "1101000 1100101 1101100 1101100 1101111"

r = [bin(int(x, base=2) ^ int(y, base=2))[2:].zfill(8) for x, y in zip(p.split(' '), q.split(' '))]

print(' '.join(r))
```

Output:

```
01100111 00110100 11010011 10010110 11000100
```